# ATG REST service not getting raw POST JSON data from POSTMAN

Tags: java, rest, web-services, atg, oracle-commerce

Iam trying to invoke ATG Rest service from POSTMAN, Passing JSON as a raw in the body. Webservice is not getting data,It is coming as null input.
But when i pass same input JSON as x-www-form-urlencoded, with key and value pair ,input data(orderJson) is coming fine.

Here is my code in webservice to get input json from POSTMAN.

Rest endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/bean/com/order/CreateOrder/processOrder
```

Method:

```
public JSONObject processOrder(String orderJson) throws ServletException,IOException {
 System.out.println("orderJson = " + orderJson);
}
```

Even when I tried to read raw JSON as below code, the data is not coming:

```
bufferedReader = req.getReader();

try {
    InputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
```

What should be wrong when we pass input json as raw from body with POST?

Screenshot for x-www-form-urlencoded:

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded]

Comment: It would be nice if you have posted complete request. POSTMAN has this option to copy CODE (in the same row as Headers, Body) of request.

Comment: When using "raw" input, you need to make sure to specify the data type in a header like `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: Yes,Content-type and Accept are added in header.But still not working. It is working only when x-www-form-urlencoded or form-data options selected with passing arg1 and value as request JSON as per screenshot

Comment: @WaqasMemon..Here the request: {"code":200,"message":"Your Order is being processed","transactionID":["o1276690256"]}